# how can i migrate my android application from Cordova for Android 4.1.1 to higher version

Tags: android, cordova

For my existing android application i got the warning from google play store that i need to migrate my application from Cordova for Android 4.1.1 to higher version ?
Could anyone help please to get the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After installing the cordova utility, you can always update it to the latest version by running the following command:

```
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
```

Use this syntax to install a specific version:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0
```

Run cordova -v to see which version is currently running. To find the latest released cordova version, you can run:

```
$ npm info cordova version
```

To update platform that you're targeting:

```
$ cordova platform update android --save
$ cordova platform update ios --save
```

...etc.